# Is there a way to emulate Windows in Linux like WSL?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, wine, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My question is: Is there something like LSW (Linux subsystem for Windows) for Linux? If yes, which and how do I install it? Please avoid comments like "Why would you want to do this?" because I'm really interested in this.

Comment: I can't see anyone asking "why"... but what exactly you do want to achieve? Run a full Windows OS under Linux? VirtualBox, KVM/QEMU, VMWare Player. Run some Windows applications? Wine. Run PowerShell? You can install that on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux system calls are published, then it is "easy" for Microsoft to develop a Linux Subsystem (WSL1). And this subsystem can run an ecosystem (programs, libraries...) which is free to copy.

On the other hand, the Windows system calls are not published and subject to change (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489889/system-calls-in-windows-native-api). What is published is the libraries which call these system calls, and you can't copy freely these libraries without copyright infringement. Then the way Wine developpers follow is emulating these DLL.

But both ways (WSL1, Wine) are similar but not stricly equivalent : emulating some functions (Linux Syscall, Windows DLL).

WSL2 is built differently since it includes a Linux kernel.

Answer (score 1):

There is `wine` it is equivalent of WSL1. WSL2 is just Gnu/Linux in a virtual machine. So, use a virtual machine.